# JQuery selecting right div

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slideleft button').click(function() {
    var $lefty = $(this).next();
    $lefty.animate({
      left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ?
        -$lefty.outerWidth() :
        0
    });
  });
});
```

This is the code i currently have, however i want the click function on a div called menu, no problems thus far, however i want to still make it slide the same div in and out but i just can't seem to find the right thing to do, i need to change this bit `$(this).next();` but i have no clue to what, i tried many things but none seem to respond.

Help is always appreciated!

Comment: To know how to traverse your DOM we'd need to see your relevant html. Otherwise we're guessing, based on no information.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ID of the div you still want to slide (we'll say 'myDiv'), you can use a selector for that specific div instead of `$(this).next()`. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu').click(function() {  //this now references the menu div
    var $lefty = $('#myDiv');    //this is the id of the div you want to slide
    $lefty.animate({
      left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ?
        -$lefty.outerWidth() :
        0
    });
  });
});
```

`$(this).next()` is referencing a div that is relative to `$('#slideleft button')`, if you want to keep the reference to this div relative, we'll need to see your HTML markup to know where to look.

Comment: This worked, i actually entered it wrong the first time i tried it so i had some trouble figuring it out, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slideleft button').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();

  });
});
```